# Why empty set needs to be defined in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Zerok series on Mathematical Analysis, **Basic Concepts of Mathematics** writes

> It is also convenient to introduce the so-called *empty* set, denoted by $\emptyset$ , I.e. a set that contains no elements at all. Instead of saying that there are no objects of some specific kind, we shall say that the set of these elements is empty; *however , this set itself, though empty, will be regarded as an existing thing*.

Now, my question is why there was a need to define the empty set? If I consider the empty set as an analog of number *zero* then also I’m unable to conclude any meaningful conclusion for defining the empty set, *zero* is a great number you can’t divide anyone (I mean a number) by it.

The thing that is not conceivable by me is the phrase *though empty, will be regraded as an existing thing* .

Comment: It's handy to express the fact that two sets are disjoint $A \cap B = \emptyset$. So we must allow the empty set if we want to define intersections. In fact, the comprehension axiom that says $\{x \in y: \phi(x)\}$ is a set whenever $y$ is and $\phi(x)$ some set property, already implies there is $\emptyset$ as soon as we have but one set.

Comment: How do you prove that $0$ exists?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I haven’t understood that $\{ x \varepsilon y : \phi (x) \}$ part. Can you please please explain it.

Comment: Do you know the comprehension axiom?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that "$0$ is a number" you're saying that it exists in a certain axiomatic framework that formalises the idea of "numbers". For example, the natural numbers.

When we say that "$\varnothing$ exists" we simply say that there is a set which has no elements. I suspect that you're a bit confused by the phrasing of the text, as it seems to imply that you might expect that "a set has elements" and since the empty set has none, it cannot truly be a set. And the text is clarifying around that.